# Fetch, getting a 400 error reading the JSON

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api

I am making a save operation that when the data is invalid the response is a 400 HTTP status with the details in the JSON body.  I want to read the JSON so I can display it below is the code I have been using but nothing seems to work on getting a 400 error body response

```
  private _onSave() {
    let e: EmployeeSaveEntity = this.state.employeeSave;
    this._save(e, this._onResponse.bind(this) , this._onCheckError.bind(this));  
  }

  public _save(employee: EmployeeSaveEntity, onFulfilled: any, onReject: any) {
    let url: string = __URL__;
    url += 'Employees';

    let context: any = this;
    let res: Promise<Response>;
    try {
        res = fetch(url,
            {   
                //"cors" | "navigate" | "same-origin" | "no-cors"
                //mode:"no-cors",
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': `Bearer ${context._authentication.token.access_token}`,
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                },
                body: employee.getJSON()
            }).then(onFulfilled, onReject);
        }
        catch (error) {
            throw new Error('Failed to save employee');
        };
}

  private _onCheckError(value: any) {
    console.log('_onCheckError');
    console.log(value);
  }

  private _onResponse(value: Response) {    
    console.log('_onResponse');
    console.log(value);
    console.log( value.text() );
    value.json().then(this._onJson.bind(this), this._onCheckError.bind(this));
  }
  private _onJson(value: any) {

    console.log('_onJson');
    console.log(value);
  }
```

> HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request Cache-Control: no-cache Pragma: no-cache
>   Transfer-Encoding: chunked Content-Type: application/json;
>   charset=utf-8 Expires: -1 Date: Fri, 20 Oct 2017 14:50:33 GMT
>   X-Response-From: 10.50.46.29
>
> {"HierId":[
>   "You can not insert master table data into the system at this hierarchy level."
>   ],
>   "PrimaryPhoneNumberCountryCallingCode":[
>   "The PrimaryPhoneNumberCountryCallingCode is required when PrimaryPhoneNumber has a value."
>   ]
>   }

Comment: You aren't sending `content-length` in your headers. That may be an issue. From the RFC, "Applications SHOULD use this field to indicate the transfer-length of the message-body, unless this is prohibited by the rules in section 4.4."

Comment: `application/json` does **not** have a charset.

Comment: The content-length is not needed the fetch appends it to the header.  This all works when the data is correct I get a response 200 back an everything works.  What I really want to know is how do you read the body of a Bad Request.

Answer (score 0):

Since the HTTP request was successful (you got *any* response) then the result will just be passed to `onFulfilled` method.

Look at this example:

```
fetch("/error").then((response) => { 
    console.log(response.status);  //400 in your case
    response.json().then((errorJson) => {
        console.log(errorJson); // should return the error json
    }); 
})
```

Comment: That is similar to the example I used but my status comes back as 0.  I have to add mode:"no-cors", to my request to get it any further, and then I get the following message  **Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at eval (eval at ./components/employee.tsx (app.5319b150089f3650765c.js:8370), <anonymous>:233:26)
    at <anonymous>**

Comment: @user1730289  Adding "mode: 'no-cors'" tells browsers to block your frontend JavaScript code from any access to the response.

Comment: K but I do not add it I get this **Failed to load https://domain/Employees: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.**

Comment: @user1730289 Adding "mode: 'no-cors'" isn’t a fix for that problem. It just obscures the real problem by causing a different less-obvious problem

Comment: In order to CORS work, you need to set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` to the HTTP response headers on your server. Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS